# How to set up hotkey for toggling wireless?

Tags: wireless, shortcut-keys

After messing around with GNOME desktop in Ubuntu 14.10 (I went back to Unity), my WLAN key doesn't work anymore. All the other keys (volume up/down, turn off screen, mute, etc) work except for the wireless toggle key.

If I go to keyboard shortcuts and modify any shortcut by typing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (that's my wireless toggle button) then it shows that the button 'WLAN' was pressed. However I don't know how to assign that button to do its job.

Here is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a file called `wifi.sh`.
2. Copy these lines to it:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/sh

   if [ $(nmcli nm wifi | awk '/led/ {print}') = 'enabled'  ] ; then
       nmcli nm wifi off
       echo 'wifi off'
   else
       nmcli nm wifi on
       notify-send -i network-wireless-none "Wireless" "Wireless enabled"
       echo 'wifi on'
   fi
   ```
3. [Make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/a/35528/298362).
4. Remember its full path so, for example, if you create `wifi.sh` in your `Desktop` then its full path is `/home/USERNAME/Desktop/wifi.sh` (replace `USERNAME` with your user's name).

4. In *System Settings* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* window, press on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign to add a new keyboard shortcut and write the full path for `wifi.sh` file in the second box (for example `/home/ahed/.config/wifi.sh`). Then click on the *Disable* word and then press your wireless key.

Optional if the above have not worked:

5. Open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and install `dconf-editor` if not installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
6. Run it:

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
7. Go to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0` and check the binding value. It should be `XF86WLAN` instead of `WLAN` (double click to change it).

Comment: I'll try this. What is the original directory for wifi.sh? It used to work before, but after messing with the desktop it stopped working. So I guess this was already implemented in some place.

Comment: original directory , it's up to you ,but i prefer home directory (~), or config directory (~/.config) which is hidden . right click on any file then click properties , you'll see it's path next to location

Answer (score 1):

Currently `urfkill` service provides the killswitch hotkey support system-wide. Simply `apt-get install urfkill` and the wifi toggle should work.

Comment: Works perfectly on a Samsung RF511 under KDE NEON / Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following worked for me

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $(nmcli radio wifi) = 'enabled'  ] ; then
    nmcli radio wifi off
    notify-send -i network-wireless-none "Wireless" "Wireless disabled"
    echo 'wifi off'
else
    nmcli radio wifi on
    notify-send -i network-wireless-none "Wireless" "Wireless enabled"
    echo 'wifi on'
fi
```